# Unable to debug Windows Store app. (specified file is not in a registry file format)

Tags: c#, uwp, registry, iot

I made a very simple software, which is for checking time, weather (openweathermap API), and indoor temperature (serial communication with Android).

I used it for several months well. Recently, I got a problem and I cannot solve this one. Please refer below message.

[image]

If I set a debugging mode as a my PC like below, it is working fine.
[image]

However, if I set a debugging mode as my raspberry pi like below, it shows the above pop-up message.

[image]

For me, the error message is too ambiguous and I am not sure what to do.
(I can access my raspberry pi with IoT Dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the 'Local Machine' to 'Remote Machine'.
[image]

This article shows how to [deploy and debug your application is straightforward with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appdeployment).

In addition, i'm confused about that when solution platform is ARM, there will be no 'Local Machine' item in the target device list by default.My Visual Studio is 2017.15.6.2. 
[image]